# strlen and size of for character arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char p[5];
   char q[]="Hello";
   int i=0;

   strcpy(p,"Hello");
   printf("strlen(p)=%d\n",strlen(p));
   printf("sizeof(p)=%d\n",sizeof(p));
   printf("strlen(q)=%d\n",strlen(q));
   printf("sizeof(q)=%d\n",sizeof(q));
   for(i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
      printf("p[%d]=%c\tq[%d]=%c\n",i,p[i],i,q[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The output that I get is:

```
strlen(p)=5
sizeof(p)=5
strlen(q)=5
sizeof(q)=6
p[0]=H  q[0]=H
p[1]=e  q[1]=e
p[2]=l  q[2]=l
p[3]=l  q[3]=l
p[4]=o  q[4]=o
p[5]=   q[5]=
```

1. I know declaring array like q[]="some string" sets the size of the array equal to the number of characters in the string const, but why is there a difference in the output of sizeof() for both the types of array declaration?
2. How does the strlen() & the printf() know when to stop, there was no null character added while declaring the two arrays.

Comment: when you understand how important is the 0x0 or '\0' or Null char... you will not need this question anymore...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple questions in your question.

> ```
> strcpy(p,"Hello");
> ```

- This is illegal since `p` is only 5 chars long, so **there's no room
  left for the terminating 0** added by `strcpy`. Consequently it is
  either not 0-terminated or the 0 byte was added outside the available
  space - calling `strlen` on it is also undefined behavior or fishy at
  least
- Calling `sizeof` on `p` is okay and yields the correct value of 5.
- Calling `strlen(q)` yields 5 because q indeed contains a 0 terminator - **implicitly added by initializing with a string literal** - and there are 5 chars before the 0
- Since it contains a 0 terminator, `q` is really **an array of 6
  characters** so `sizeof` yields 6.

Comment: The strcpy does an "overflow" and writes NULL character into the next byte (6th) for p[]. And since strlen calculates the length based on the position of the NULL character-1, it works fine. So, the result is not fishy/undefined here, it'll always be the same. The problem is with C implementation of strlen.

Answer (score 1):

```
char p[5];
strcpy(p,"Hello");
```

copies 5 characters into `p` and writes the terminating null-character (`'\0'`) at 6th position, i.e. out of the bounds of this array, which yields ***undefined behavior***.

From manual page of [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy):

> *"If the destination string of a strcpy() is not large enough, then **anything might happen**. Any time a program reads or copies data into a buffer, the program first needs to check that there's enough space."*

Answer (score 0):

```
   char p[5];

   strcpy(p,"Hello");
```

This strcpy writes a 0 into p[5]. So it's out of bounds. The sizeof(p) is still 5 though.
You have written over the end of p. It's incorrect and results in undefined behavior. In
this case nothing bad happened and it went unnoticed.

The other string you have, has a length of 5 and a sizeof 6.

Answer (score 0):

The `q` char array also contains the null terminating character. While the fixed size of `p` doesn't allow the null character to be copied in. Notice that `strlen` will check for the null character to count the amount of characters of a string, therefore not having one will probably cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(q) is 6, since it contains null terminator.

p does not hold enough space for the null terminator - so strlen(p) can be any random value. This is called undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C are terminated by a `NUL` character '\0';

This is why `sizeof(q)` returns 6, it has enough space to store the `'\0'` at the end.
You've sized p yourself to be able to hold 5 characters, not enough for the trailing `'\0'`.

So, this code is undefined behaviour:

`strcpy(p, "Hello");`

This is copying the `'\0'` into `p[5]`, which is out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Question: why is there a difference in the output of sizeof() for both the types of array declaration?

Answer: This statement declares a variable named q, with type char[], pointing at a memory location that holds "Hello".

```
char q[] = "Hello";
```

sizeof(q) is 6 because the string "Hello" is comprised of 'H','e','l','l','o','\0', which includes the NULL char in the count.

This statement declares a variable named p, with type char[], pointing to a memory location where 5 char's are reserved.

```
char p[5];
```

Note that depending upon memory alignment flags to the compiler, you may actually have 6, 8, or more char's reserved at the location reserved to p.  And C won't complain if you reference or assign p[5] (which is the ordinal sixth char in the p[] array).

sizeof(p) is 5 because the compiler has recorded how big the memory location you declared for p.  So sizeof(p) and sizeof(q) return different values because p and q are declared differently and refer to different entities.

Question: How does the strlen() & the printf() know when to stop, there was no null character added while declaring the two arrays.

Answer: Both strlen() function calls count the number of non-NULL char's.  So both strlen function calls count char's until they locate the NULL terminator.  Which both p and q have, at least until the memory location at p+5 is assigned another value.  This is because p and q are both allocated on the stack.  Look at the addresses of p, q, and the integer i.  Here is your function with additional variables added to help illustrate where p and q are located,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define min(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define max(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(b):(a))

int main()
{
   char m0 = 'X';
   char p[5];
   char m1 = 'Y';
   char q[]="Hello";
   char m2 = 'Z';
   int i=0;

   strcpy(p,"World");
   printf("strlen(p)=%d\n",strlen(p));
   printf("sizeof(p)=%d\n",sizeof(p));
   printf("strlen(q)=%d\n",strlen(q));
   printf("sizeof(q)=%d\n",sizeof(q));
   for(i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
      printf("p[%d]=%c\tq[%d]=%c\n",i,p[i],i,q[i]);
   }
   printf("m0=%x, %c\n",&m0,m0);
   printf(" p=%x\n",p);
   printf("m1=%x, %c\n",&m1,m1);
   printf(" q=%x\n",q);
   printf("m2=%x, %c\n",&m2,m2);
   char *x;
   for(x=min(&m0,&m2);x<max(&m0,&m2);x++)
   {
      printf("x[%x]=%c\n",x,*x);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Observe that m0, m1, and m2 are adjacent to the arrays p[] and q[].  When run on my Linux system, we observe that the strcpy of "World" modifies the value of m0 (replaces the 'X' with '\0').

```
strlen(p)=5
sizeof(p)=5
strlen(q)=5
sizeof(q)=6
p[0]=W  q[0]=H
p[1]=o  q[1]=e
p[2]=r  q[2]=l
p[3]=l  q[3]=l
p[4]=d  q[4]=o
p[5]=   q[5]=
m0=bfbea6a7, 
 p=bfbea6a2
m1=bfbea6a1, Y
 q=bfbea69b
m2=bfbea69a, Z
x[bfbea69a]=Z
x[bfbea69b]=H
x[bfbea69c]=e
x[bfbea69d]=l
x[bfbea69e]=l
x[bfbea69f]=o
x[bfbea6a0]=
x[bfbea6a1]=Y
x[bfbea6a2]=W
x[bfbea6a3]=o
x[bfbea6a4]=r
x[bfbea6a5]=l
x[bfbea6a6]=d
x[bfbea6a7]=
```

A C literal string such as "Hello" or "World" is terminated by the NULL char, and includes that char in the size of the string.  The strcpy() function copies the entire string, including the NULL char at the end.

You should use strncpy, or check the destination string size.  Note that when you used strcpy(p,q), you copied more characters (the NULL terminator) than p[] had allocated.  That is something you want to avoid.  C does not do boundary checking on arrays, so it will let you perform the strcpy.  Though lint would detect this error.